# Creating additional users to access Mac OS X VPN Server

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, user-accounts

On my privat iMac, I configured the VPNd that comes with the system and is just hidden. 
I used the following manual.

http://blog.theilluminatedengineer.com/?p=136

It is working fine for my primary user and authenticates without any problem. Now I want to create a second user to access files on my network. I just added another user, but this user is not able to authenticate. I can't find anything on the web so far to show me what criteria a user needs to match to be able to authenticate against the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please post result of

```
dscl . read /users/username AuthenticationAuthority
```

where username is the short name of new user? It should be something like:

```
;ShadowHash; ;ShadowHash;HASHLIST:<SALTED-SHA1,SMB-NT,SMB-LAN-MANAGER>
```

if not please execute following command:

```
sudo dscl . change /users/username AuthenticationAuthority ;ShadowHash; ;ShadowHash;HASHLIST:<SALTED-SHA1,SMB-NT,SMB-LAN-MANAGER>
```

Courtesy of [MacOSXHints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060616150640529).